# json - can't access json parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my code

```
var data = '{"coord":{"lon":74.34,"lat":31.55},"weather":[{"id":711,"main":"Smoke","description":"smoke","icon":"50d"},{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":304.6,"pressure":1002,"humidity":62,"temp_min":304.15,"temp_max":305.15},"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":130},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1466901000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7133,"message":0.0035,"country":"PK","sunrise":1466899176,"sunset":1466950287},"id":1172451,"name":"Lahore","cod":200}'
    setWeather(data);

function setWeather(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    alert(json['main']['temp']);
    $('#temp').html(json['main']['temp']);
}
```

And I can't seem to figure out why I'm not able to access the json object parameter. Anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` this does exactly... _Nothing_. Remove the stringify.

Comment: What do you think `JSON.stringify` does? The steps to debug this would be to log the value return by `JSON.stringify(data)` and returned by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`. Then you probably would have already found out why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you stringify JSON you have to parse a parsed result and would need to do `var obj = JSON.parse((JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));` ... what's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 3):

Let us to some basic debugging:

```
> var data = '{"coord": ... }';
> typeof data
  "string"
```

So far so good, `data` is a string.

```
> JSON.stringify(data);
""{\"coord\": ... }""
> typeof JSON.stringify(data);
  "string"
```

Apparently `JSON.stringify(data)` also returns a string. We can see the same value contained in `data` but now including surrounding quotes (note the double `""` at the beginning and the end) and escaped quotes (`\"`).

So what exactly does `JSON.stringify` do? It will convert any JavaScript value **to** JSON. Some examples:

```
> JSON.stringify([]) // array
  "[]"
> JSON.stringify(true) // array
  "true"
> JSON.stringify("foo") // string  
  ""foo""
```

We can see that passing a string simply produces another JSON encoded string, so that doesn't seem particular helpful. But you are also using `JSON.parse`, so lets see what effect that has:

```
> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  "{"coord": ... }"
> typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  "string"
```

It seems using `JSON.parse` returns a string again. This shouldn't be too surprising since we are passing a *string value* to `JSON.stringify`, which will encode it as a JSON string. Parsing this result must give us back the original value, which was a string. We can verify that easily:

```
> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) === data
  true
```

Yep.

So that doesn't help us converting `data` to a JavaScript object. Lets just try `JSON.parse` instead:

```
> JSON.parse(data)
  Object {coord: Object, weather: Array[2], base: "cmc stations", main: Object, wind: Object…}
```

That looks much better. Since `data` contains a JSON encoded object, `JSON.parse` converts that value to a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

I your example, `data` is a string, not a javascript object, so you don't need to use `JSON.stringify`, remove it and it should work:

```
var data = '{"coord":{"lon":74.34,"lat":31.55},"weather":[{"id":711,"main":"Smoke","description":"smoke","icon":"50d"},{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":304.6,"pressure":1002,"humidity":62,"temp_min":304.15,"temp_max":305.15},"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":130},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1466901000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7133,"message":0.0035,"country":"PK","sunrise":1466899176,"sunset":1466950287},"id":1172451,"name":"Lahore","cod":200}'
    setWeather(data);

function setWeather(data) {
    //NOTE: only parse is needed
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(json['main']['temp']);
    $('#temp').html(json['main']['temp']);
}
```

Comment: *"I your example, data is a string, not JSON"* uhm, `data` is a string *containing* JSON. Are you confusing "JSON" with JavaScript values / objects?

Comment: *"data is a string, not JSON"* ... huh? what do you think JSON is by defintion?

Answer (score 0):

**data** is a String because of the single quotes , so if you called JSON.stringify(data) will add another double quotes to **data**  , which means in order to [convert data to JS object](https://bassamrubaye.me/javascript-operators/) you will need to call JSON.parse(data) two times .

```
 var obj ='{hello:1}';  //string



var json= JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);               // "\"{hello:1}\""

console.log(JSON.parse(json));   //"{hello:1}"    => still a string
```

To get your code running correctly by converting data to object , just remove the JSON.stringify()

```
function setWeather(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // remove JSON.stringify() => now json is object
    alert(json['main']['temp']);
    $('#temp').html(json['main']['temp']);
}
```